# jQuery delay or JavaScript SetTimeOut Simple solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, delay

I need to set an alert nice message box via Jquery-UI 
and then after the effects of the animation is done , and only then 
to navigate to a different URL

This is the code I am using though no matter what I did try 
the navigation occurs... only the UI effects does not get the chance to perform.

```javascript
$("#dialog").dialog({
            show: { effect: "puff", duration: 2000 },
            hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 500 },
            height: 340,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "אישור": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close").delay(2000).delay(800, function () {
                        window.location = "http://rcl.co.il";
                    });

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try bind redirect function on `dialogclose` event.

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/tDFq3/

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
            show: { effect: "puff", duration: 2000 },
            hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 500 },
            height: 340,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "אישור": function () {
                    $(this).on('dialogclose', function () {
                        window.location = "http://rcl.co.il";
                    }).dialog('close');

                }
            }
        });
```